# How to send email on shutdown?

Tags: shutdown

I am using **msmtp** to send an email to my email address whenever my server is started and I'd like to make the server send an email when it shuts down as well. I've tried writing a simple script (the script itself works properly) and linking it to `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d`, but without any effect. How can I properly exectue that script on shutdown?

Comment: What is the contents of your script you are trying to run?

Comment: echo "Server shutdown" | msmtp email@address

Comment: Does your script change a file if you echo something to a file? How did you create the link, did you use the absolute or relative path ? Cheers.

Comment: That should be preceded with `#!/bin/sh` and the full path to `msmtp` needs to be specified.

Comment: Forgot to add that. The script itself works, a similar script already sends me an email when the server boots up. The problem is most likely that the script gets executed too late into the shutdown process.

Comment: It should run fine if done  early in the shutdown, name it something  like *K01sendmail* the "KXX" is the order the scripts are run in `/etc/rc0.d` about "K07" is when the network gets shut down.

Comment: The script is named AMailOnShutdown and executes following code:

`#!/bin/bash 
echo "Subject: Server shutdown" | msmtp email@address`

I created the script in `/etc/init.d/` and linked it using `ln -s` to `/etc/rc0.d/` and `/etc/rc6.d/`.

Comment: I renamed my file to `K01MailOnShutdown` and linked it with `ln -s` to `/etc/rc0.d/` and `/etc/rc6.d/`, but sadly it did not work.

Comment: You don't want to link it to the directory, Just copy your script to `/etc/rc0.d/` at runlevel "0" all the scripts in that directory get run.

Comment: It did not work for some reason. The last thing I could think of would be that I'm always using the `shutdown` command to shut the server down.